Config.properties changes not impacting even after clearing the cache in maven project
I switched my branch from project to another and there were few config.properties file changes in the new branch. Even after clearing the cache multiple times, building the application again, and restarting the server, the changes in the latest file are not reflected in the application.
Any suggestion would help.
Tried Clearing cache, rebuilding the application and restarting the server. Nothing worked. Cant access the new variable which is now found in the new branch in the application

config.properties makes me believe its Eclipse you are using? If so, good to add as a "marker" to the question. Also, when I use maven in Eclipse lot of stuff get fixed by "Update Project" or by Maven-> clean. Then Maven -> Install.

I can try to list up things here, but really you need to figure out as something is wrong with your local setup

maven clean install
Local github repo cache cleanup
Eclipse cache clean up (you can get some help from search engines)
Create new Eclipse workspace


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
